# How to automatically enter information into <input> via parameters from URL?

Tags: html

I am looking to automatically enter information into an HTML  via adding parameters in the url (for example google.com?param=test, where "test" will automatically be entered into the google search box). This would ideally be possible without having to modify the code whatsoever, and it could target an  with a specific class, id or name.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the function `getParameterByName(name, url)` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/4378740) to get querystring values.

Then, use JavaScript and/or jQuery to modify the input values. Example in jQuery:

```
<script>
    var param = getParameterByName('param'); // test
    $("#myId").val(param);
</script>
<input id="myId" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that by only using HTML, because it's a markup language.
To access the URL query parameters I would suggest using for example JavaScript:

```
<script>
 var url_string = window.location.href; // Current page URL
 var url = new URL(url_string);
 var param = url.searchParams.get("param");
 console.log(c);
</script>
```

In php that would be:

```
<?=$_GET['param']?>
```